# How to plot one to many plot using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

**Update**: Removing the screenshot, Below is the code from the screenshot:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(5)
y = np.array([[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,5,7,9]])

plt.plot(x,y) #gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

#A relaistic example
age = [20,30,40,50,60]
salary = np.array([[200,350,414],[300,500,612,700],[500,819],[900,1012],[812,712]])

plt.plot(age,salary) #gives ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I am having two arrays each of size 5, elements of y are arrays, and I want them to be plotted against each x, for example at x = 0, I want to plot all the points from y[0], is there a way?

**Update**: Added another example above to show a realistic case , where I need to plot different salaries of different age people, each age people can have more than one salary.

Comment: What do you want this to look like? "I want to plot" is pretty vague.

Comment: At X=0 I want two dots one at y=1 and another at y=2, similarly at X=1, I want three dots at y=1,y=2,y=3 and so on. In some places I saw such graphs , for example plotting all the salaries of different age people and then there will be a line showing average value at each points.

Comment: @BigBen, removed the screenshot, updated with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[List comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-use-it) to the rescue!

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

age = [20,30,40,50,60]
salary = np.array([[200,350,414],[300,500,612,700],[500,819],[900,1012],[812,712]])

#creating x-y tuples
xy = [(k, j) for i, k in enumerate(age) for j in salary[i]]

#unpacking the tuples with zip
plt.scatter(*zip(*xy))

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image: ![enter image description here]

However, irregular numpy arrays should not be created, and this example works perfectly well with a normal list. Just saying.

Comment: I populated age and salary with random data, and your code performed more than 5 times better than mine where I was calling plot() method as many times as many points were there. 
<code>
age = np.arange(200)
salary = []

for a in age:
    sz = np.random.randint(20)
    arr = []
    for s0 in np.arange(sz):
        data = np.random.randint(20000)
        arr.append(data)
    salary.append(arr)
</code>

Comment: You can look at list comprehensions as an optimized version of a for-loop. I linked to some explanation on list comprehension; you should familiarize yourself with this great Python tool.

Answer (score 0):

As of now I am using the following workaround, but looking for a simpler solution:

```
indx = -1
for a in age:
    indx+=1
    for s in salary[indx]:
        plt.plot(a,s,'o')
plt.show()
```

Comment: What's wrong with this approach? I mean, you should specify the color but apart from that?

Comment: In this approach , I am calling the plot method as many times as many points are there to be plotted , hence taking more time , I tested with a dataset of 200 , in x , axis, and mine was taking 5 sec + while yours took few milliseconds, Thanks